# SSIS package doesnt work on server

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis, sql-data-tools

I've made a package that works nicly on my dev-computer but when I copy the dtsx-file over to my SQL2014 it doesnt work properly.
The Packages inkludes a OLE DB-source that runs a sql-question and stores the result into a resultset. I then have a foreach-loop that runs a script for each row in the resultset. Right now the script just calls `this.Dts.Events.FireInformation(1, "Testing", "Testing", "", 0, ref fireAgain);`

When I run it on the SQL-server I get that 1 row is written to the resultset, but nothing else (other than validation-status).

Looks like it does run the script-task at all, but what do I do wrong?
I'm running VS2015 on my dev-computer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to know what it's doing, check the logs. Then you'll know whether its running the script task. Who knows - you might even find an _error_ that is the key to solving the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend helped me remember that I run this on a diffrent SQL-version than I normally work with, so I had forgot to change server target-version.